# Capture domain in Laravel routes file as url variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a problem capturing the domain in the routes file.

When a route is written like this:

```php
Route::domain('mydomain.com')
    ->get('/', function () {
        return "It works";
    });
```

And I access `mydomain.com`, I correctly get status `200` and a string `It works`.

But when the routes are changed to this:

```php
Route::domain('{domain}')
    ->get('/', function () {
        return "It works";
    });
```

It is not getting picked up and I get `404`.

I was also trying:

```php
Route::bind('domain', function () {
    return 'mydomain.com';
});

Route::domain('{domain}')
    ->get('/', function () {
        return "It works";
    });
```

But it is not working either.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have [`Route::bind`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) inside a `ServiceProvider`'s `boot` method? Why are you using `Route::domain`?

Comment: What? I did not understand. If you do have one single Laravel installation, you do NOT need to use `Route::domain` or anything similar, just specify the routes...

Comment: But I have multiple domains pointing to the installation. How would you serve different home pages for mywebsite.com and lets say mywebsite.de?

Comment: Okay, that is different then, you did not mention that. I am not sure what is changing in your system based on the domain, but usually you do just point the domain to the `public` folder and done, you do not need anything more to do, but again, you did not mention what is changing in your system based on the domain. But you got it working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a custom pattern for the {domain} parameter using regular expressions.

```
Route::pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.-]+'); // Define pattern for the domain parameter

Route::domain('{domain}')
    ->get('/', function ($domain) {
        return "It works for {$domain}";
    });
```

Comment: Awesome that works. But is there a way to specify the pattern only for a given route. Or given route group?